# Information in a Markov Process

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, information-theory, simulation

I have a system that can be simulated with a Markov process $M_1$, but it could also be simulated with a higher order Markov process $M_n$, which has memory for 1 or more previous states. Is there a way to measure how well $M_1$ versus $M_n$ represents/captures information in the system?

I would like to generate simulated data from a data set I have, and I think a Markov (high order or not) process is likely the best way to do it, but I want an explicit measure for how well different types of Markov processes replicate the data I am interested in. Perhaps there may be something in information theory that can measure this.

Comment: How much information theory are you familiar with?  Calculating the entropy of a Markov chain is fairly elementary.

Comment: If you'd like a reference, Cover and Thomas is a great text that can get you up to speed pretty quickly.

Comment: As I understand it, given a trajectory of a process, you want to figure out the smallest $n$ such that it can be represented as a $n$th order Markov chain. This is usually called the order estimation problem, and is reasonably well studied. This [paper of Csiszar & Shields](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-6/The-consistency-of-the-BIC-Markov-order-estimator/10.1214/aos/1015957472.full) is a classic reference (although it's 20 years old, so likely much has happened since).